# How to use remote control unit of android streamer box

Tags: android, selenium, automation, appium

I need to set up automation project for android tv streamer app.
I need to send keys from the remote control.

I found the KEYCODES of the dpad, but how to use them on the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see how to write effective questions in stackoverflow. (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: @SarthakJoshi, Yep you'r right.

I'm tried this code '((AndroidDriver<?>) driver()).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.DPAD_LEFT));' and it's work.
Do you have a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

((AndroidDriver) driver()).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.DPAD_LEFT));

Comment: You can edit your question, click > `edit` below the question.